# Models of higher Chern-Simons type

Tags: quantum-field-theory, research-level, gauge-theory, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

It has long been clear that (the action functional of) [Chern-Simons theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Chern-Simons+theory) has various higher analogs and variations of interest. This includes of course traditional [higher dimensional Chern-Simons theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/higher+dimensional+Chern-Simons+theory) (abelian and non-abelian) as well as the algebroid-version: the [Courant-sigma model](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Courant%20sigma-model), but also seemingly more remote systems such as [string field theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/string%20field%20theory) (and hence essentialy also its [effective truncations](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/string+field+theory#ReferencesOnYMTheoryAspects)), a fact that is already somewhat remarkable.

In a recent [article](http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/Higher+Chern-Weil+Derivation+of+AKSZ+Sigma-Models) we claimed that there is a systematic sense in which also all [AKSZ sigma-models](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/AKSZ+sigma-model) are special cases of a general abstract notion of "[infinity-Chern-Simons theory](http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/infinity-Chern-Simons+theory)". These AKSZ models include, in turn, also the [Poisson sigma-model](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Poisson%20sigma-model) (hence also the [A-model](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/A-model) and the [B-model](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/B-model)). Also [BF-theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/BF-theory) coupled to [topological Yang-Mills theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological%20Yang-Mills%20theory) fits in.

Therefore in a precise sense all these systems are examples of a single underlying basic mechanism. My **question** is: can you point out other models of interest in the literature (or in your drawer) that look like they might be "of generalized Chern-Simons type", along these lines? (I am not just looking, say, for "Chern-Simons term"-summands in higher [supergravity](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/D%27Auria-Fre+formulation+of+supergravity) actions, even though these are related, but for example new variants of full higher dimensional [Chern-Simons (super)gravity](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Chern-Simons%20gravity).)

For instance: has there been a proposal for a nonabelian 7-dimensional Chern-Simons-type model that might be the holographic partner to the [self-dual](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/self-dual+higher+gauge+theory) nonabelian [6d (2,0)-superconformal QFT](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/6d+%282,0%29-supersymmetric+QFT) (so that the state spaces of the former are the conformal blocks of the latter)? While we did come across a natural non-abelian 7-dimensional Chern-Simons type TQFT whose fields are string-2-connections ([here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/differential%20fivebrane%20structure)), I am not sure how to see if this might be the relevant one. Do you?

Comment: I'm confused -- the 6d (2,0) theories are dual to M-theory on AdS$_7 \times S^4$. Doesn't that preclude them being dual to a Chern-Simons theory?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Let's see, maybe I mean just the 2-form part of it. I was reasoning like this, please let me know if this makes sense to you: in the abelian situation the 6d theory is supposed to contain a self-dual 2-form field. These are known (sometimes even defined this way) as the boundary theory of 7d abelian CS theory, as in hep-th/9610234. I gather the search is on for the nonabelian generalization of the self-dual 2-form theory, hence it seems we should also expect there to be a corresponding nonabelian generalization of that 7d CS theory.

Comment: If you are talking about higher Chern-Simons, you should be able to answer this: [gravitational-chern-simons-theory](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/111846/gravitational-chern-simons-theory-for-boson-and-fermions)

Comment: this may be of your interests: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/121384/

Answer (score 11):

We have thought a bit about the last paragraph of the above question and have some arguments as to what the answer should be. Since there have been no replies here so far, maybe I am allowed to hereby suggest an answer myself.

Recall, the last part of the above question was: is there a nonabelian 7-dimensional Chern-Simons theory holographically related to the nonabelian $(2,0)$-theory on coincident M5-branes, and if so, does it involve the Lagrangian that controls [differential 5-brane structures](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/differential%20fivebrane%20structure)?

The following is an argument for the answer: Yes.

First, in Witten's *AdS/CFT correspondence and TFT* ([hep-th/9812012](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9812012)) a careful analysis of $AdS_5 /CFT_4$-duality shows that the spaces of conformal blocks of the 4d CFT are to be identified with the spaces of states of (just) the Chern-Simons-type Lagrangians inside the full type II action. At the very end of the article it is suggested that similarly the conformal blocks of the 6d $(2,0)$-CFT are given by the spaces of states of (just) the Chern-Simons-part inside 11d supergravity/M-theory. But there only the abelian sugra effective Lagrangian

$$
  \int_{AdS_7} \int_{S^4} C_3 \wedge G_4 \wedge G_4  = N \int_{AdS_7} C_3 \wedge G_4
$$

is briefly considered.

So we need to have a closer look at this: notice that there are two quantum corrections to the 11d sugra Chern-Simons term.

First, the 11-dimensional analog of the Green-Schwarz anomaly cancellation changes the above Chern-Simons term to (from (3.14) in [hep-th/9506126](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9506126) and ignoring prefactors here for notational simplicty)

$$
  \int_{AdS_7} \int_{S^4} C_3 (\wedge G_4 \wedge G_4 + I_8(\omega))  
  = 
  N \int_{AdS_7} \left(
     C_3 \wedge G_4  
     -
     CS_7(\omega)
  \right)
  \,,
$$

for $I_8 = \frac{1}{48}(p_2 - (\frac{1}{2}p_1)^2)$, where now the second term is the corresponding Chern-Simons 7-form evaluated in the spin connection (all locally).

So taking quantum anomaly cancellation into account, the argument of the above [hep-th/9812012](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9812012) appears to predict a *non-abelian* 7d Chern-Simons theory computing the conformal blocks of the 6d (2,0) theory, namely one whose field configurations involve both the abelian higher C-field as well as  the non-abelian spin connection field.

But there is a second quantum correction that further refines this statement: by Witten's *On Flux Quantization In M-Theory And The Effective Action* ([hep-th/9609122](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9609122)) the underlying integral 4-class $[G_4]$ of the $C$-field in the 11d bulk is constrained to satisfy

$$
  2[G_4] = \frac{1}{2}p_1 - 2a
  \,,
$$

where on the right the first term is the fractional first Pontryagin class on $B Spin$ and where $a$ is the universal 4-class of an $E_8$-bundle, the one that in Horava-Witten compactification yields the $E_8$-gauge field on the boundary of the 11d bulk. In that context, the boundary condition for the C-field is $[G_4]_{bdr} = 0$, reducing the above condition to the 10d Green-Schwarz cancellation condition.

If this boundary condition on the $C$-field is also relevant for the asymptotic $AdS_7$-boundary, then this means that what locally lookes like a Spin-connection above is really a [twisted differential String-2-connection](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/differential+string+structure) with $2a$ being the twist. As discussed in detail there, such twisted differential String-2-connections involve a further field $H_3$ such that $d H_3 = tr(F_\omega \wedge F_\omega) - tr(F_{A_{E_8}} \wedge F_{A_{E_8}}))$. Plugging this condition into the above 7-dimensional Chern-Simons action adds to the abelian $C_3$-field a Chern-Simons term for the new $H_3$-field, plus a bunch of nonabelian correction terms.

In total this argument produces a certain nonabelian 7d Chern-Simons theory whose fields are twisted String-2-connections and whose states would yield the conformal blocks of a 6d CFT. Notice that by [math/0504123](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504123) there is a gauge in which $String$-2-connections are given by loop-group valued nonabelian 2-forms (but there are other gauges in which this is not manifest). This is consistent with expectations for the "nonabelian gerbe theory" in 6d.

That's the physics argument, a more detailed writeup is in section 4.5.4.3.1 of my [notes](http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/files/cohesivedocumentv032.pdf).

Now the point is this: in the next section, 4.5.4.3.2, it is shown that, independently of all of this physics handwaving, there is naturally a fully precise 7-dimensional higher Chern-Simons Lagrangian defined on the full moduli 2-stack of twisted differential String-2-connections induced via higher Chern-Weil theory from the second fractional Pontryagin class. As discussed there, on local differential form data this reproduces precisely the nonabelian 7d Chern-Simons functional of the above argument.

We are in the process of writing this up as

Fiorenza, Sati, Schreiber, *[Nonabelian 7d Chern-Simons theory and the 5-brane](http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/7d+Chern-Simons+theory+and+the+5-brane)* . Comments are welcome.