# Gravitational Chern-Simons theory for bosons and fermions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, quantum-gravity, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

> Q1: What is the difference of boson and fermions for their **Gravitational Chern-Simons theory**?

I suppose in general if the metric is not flat, we have vierbein ${e_{\hat{b}}}^{\nu}$, with 
$$
g_{\mu\nu} {e_{\hat{a}}}^{\mu} {e_{\hat{b}}}^{\nu} = \eta_{\hat{a}\hat{b}},
$$ 
where $g_{\mu\nu}$ is curved and $\eta_{\hat{a}\hat{b}}$ is Lorentzian flat. With the spin-connection is 
$$
\omega^{\hat{c}}_{\hat{b}\mu} = 
{e^{\hat{c}}}_{\nu}\partial_\mu {e_{\hat{b}}}^{\nu} +
{\Gamma^\nu}_{\sigma\mu} {e^{\hat{c}}}_{\nu} {e_{\hat{b}}}^{\sigma},
$$ 
where ${\Gamma^\nu}_{\sigma\mu}$ are the Christoffel symbols.

**SET-UP: Now let us imagine there are some matter fields bosons $\phi$ or fermions $\psi$ coupling to the spacetime metric, and we integrate out the bosons $\phi$ or fermions $\psi$ to get the effective actions involving gravitational Chern-Simons action in 2+1D.**

So a 2+1D gravitational Chern-Simons action can be (spin connection $\omega$):
$$
S=\int\omega\wedge\mathrm{d}\omega + \frac{2}{3}\omega\wedge\omega\wedge\omega   \tag{1}
$$

I am sure this works for fermions.

> Q2: however, if bosons have spin 0 or spin 1, do we still have spin-connection? I suppose still yes?
>
> Q3: or, do we have a 2+1D gravitational Chern-Simons action for bosons to be ( the connection $\Gamma$):
>   $$
> S=\int\Gamma\wedge\mathrm{d}\Gamma + \frac{2}{3}\Gamma\wedge\Gamma\wedge\Gamma  \tag{2}
> $$
>
> Q4: what are the differences between Eq.1 and Eq.2 in terms of background matter fields? (suppose the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ is coupled to matters, either bosons or fermions.)

Please feel free give Reference. And make sure that your answer is to my point Q1-4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though standard, there is an unfortunate confusion caused by the way the term "[spin connection](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/spin%20connection)" is used in the physics literature.

The formula that you give relating the [Christoffel symbols](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Christoffel+symbols) to the $\omega$-thing with hatted indices is a formula that relates two different but equivalent local component-incarnations of the [Levi-Civita connection](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Levi-Civita%20connection). It so happends that the components expressed in $\omega$-form naturally lend themselves better to the components-description of the [minimal coupling](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Levi-Civita%20connection) term of the connection to fermions, but intrinsically, meaning up to gauge equivalences relating different local component expressions, the connection $\nabla$ which is expressed locally by "$\Gamma$" is equivalent to that locally expressed by "$\omega$", these are just two different local incarnations of what intrinsically is the same physical thing.

The real question is this: on an oriented manifold, the [Levi-Civita connection](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Levi-Civita%20connection) $\nabla$ a priori is (or gives equivalently, namely on the associated frame bundle) an $SO(n)$-[principal connection](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principal%20connection). For eventually coupling fermions to this, one needs to ask this to lift (in the sense of [G-structures](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/G-structure)) to a $Spin(n)$-principal connection.

But notice that in your question above no actual fermions ever appear. What you are really asking is for the [Chern-Simons functional](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Chern-Simons%20theory) $CS(\nabla)$ on $SO(n)$-principal connections or on $Spin(n)$-principal connections.

Check out "SO(n)-Chern-Simons theory" and the like, and maybe restate your question then.

Comment: If I understand your answer, then my Eq 1 and 2 work for the gravitational Chern-Simons theory from integrating out matter fields coupling to the metrics - both for the bosons and fermions, Eq 1 and 2 holds. So there is no such distinction. Do you agree?

Comment: What is the SO(n)-Chern-Simons theory Ref you recommend?

Comment: would you also illuminate this: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/153721/is-gravitational-chern-simons-action-topological-or-not?